# "Override" function signature of type alias

Tags: typescript

I have these types ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEFYF5YG9i07A9gOwMIAWAhrgObQBcsAFFbAKIBu0uoAlMgHyxPYCWAE2ABfEBBiwACgCdskAM7I0vYgBsArvQWgZ-crDFgocAELLEAMjQYseIqQrUakOYuqz5Czkh58hoiAAxng6sABG1OYo6Fg4BCTk9DQubgoeaT48IbgK2GrQAHRq2GSpXuzsokA)):

```js
type A = {
    onChange: (e: Event) => void
}

type Props = { value: string }

type B = A & {
    onChange: (props: Props) => void
}
```

While I can define them, I can't use them:

```js
const b: B = {
    onChange: ((props: Props) => console.log(props.value)) // error
}
```

I get this error:

```
Type '(props: Props) => void' is not assignable to type '((e: Event) => void) & ((props: Props) => void)'.
  Type '(props: Props) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: Event) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'e' are incompatible.
      Property 'value' is missing in type 'Event' but required in type 'Props'.(2322)
```

Is it possible to use the types as described and get rid of this error?

One idea that came to my mind is to use:

```js
type B = Omit<A, 'onChange'> & {
    onChange: (props: Props) => void
}
```

But it feels a bit odd, because it is not refactoring safe.

Comment: Just remove explicit type for `:Props`

Comment: This won't help if I don't want to just `console.log` but do want to access props details. I'll update the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Override` utility type-

```
type Override<T1, T2> = Omit<T1, keyof T2> & T2;
```

`Override` creates a new type (say `T3`) by omitting all the keys from `T1` which are also in `T2` (that is, the common keys). Then it creates an intersection type from `T3` and `T2`

The whole solution would be-

```
type Override<T1, T2> = Omit<T1, keyof T2> & T2;

type A = {
    propA: string
    onChange: (e: Event) => void
}

type Props = { value: string }

type B = Override<A, {
    propB: number
    onChange: (props: Props) => void
}>

const b: B = {
    onChange: ((props: Props) => console.log(props)),
    propA: 'propA',
    propB: 3
}
```

[[Playground]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhAToglgEwgHgCoEYA0U2ATAHxQC8sAtisDgVANYQgD2AZkWVAGTcBuAFBDQkKAEFKUAN5CoCqGERswEgFxQAzsFQA7AObzFbPQGEAFgENDETQAo7UAKII9wAJSVycNuiEAviJi0AAKKmBa0jJQcFYANgCuTjr6BlBBouDQAELS8EioGJgShHKKShE5mnqJ1ABGSMYKppY2Bk72yqpamuE9XhQ+fmiBpCIAxqY6UPWaeVTlJubWtg5dEb1Q-ZGD5FN6WmzxEAB08WwGGwMe+M2VqhpQAOTdas93FW-VUADMgUA)

Ref- https://dev.to/vborodulin/ts-how-to-override-properties-with-type-intersection-554l